# Can find class name, but can't find Test Method in Jmeter

Tags: java, selenium, junit, jmeter

I am trying to integrate jmeter with selenium.
I wrote a script, exported it as jar, saved it in lib/junit.
Then added a Junit request sampler to my thread. I can find the relevant class name, but the Test Method list is empty.
Here is the code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.junit.Test;


public class SeleniumTest extends TestCase{

    WebDriver driver=null;
@Before
public void setUp()  {
    driver=new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
@Test
    public void login()
    {

       driver.get("http://www.website.com/");
       try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
       driver.findElement(By.id("inputEmail")).clear();
       driver.findElement(By.id("inputEmail")).sendKeys("username");
       driver.findElement(By.id("inputPassword")).clear();
       driver.findElement(By.id("inputPassword")).sendKeys("password");
       driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.controls > button.btn")).click();
    }

@After
public void tearDown()  {
    driver.quit();
}

}
```

Comment: what version of junit are you using? junit 4 annotations will only be recognised if you tick the box. junit 3 methods must follow naming conventions

Answer (score 2):

I think that you need to change your method name to start with `test`, i.e. to `testLogin`

Also by default JMeter's JUnit Request Sampler is looking for JUnit3-style test cases naming. Looking into your code I see that you're using JUni4 annotations so you need to check "Search for JUnit4 annotations" box.

For more details on JUnit Request Sampler you can refer to How to Use [JUnit With JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter) guide.